FastAPI Email Sending Fails with SMTPConnectResponseError: Service Not Available
I'm trying to send an email to users after they sign up using FastAPI and FastAPI-Mail. However, I'm encountering an error indicating that the email service is not available. I've tried using both Yahoo and Gmail, but neither seems to work. Here's my code
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, HTTPException, status
from fastapi_mail import FastMail, MessageSchema, ConnectionConfig
import aiosmtplib
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME')

conf = ConnectionConfig(
    MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME,
    MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD,
    MAIL_FROM='email@example.com',
    MAIL_PORT=587,
    MAIL_SERVER='smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    MAIL_FROM_NAME='My name',
    MAIL_STARTTLS=True,
    MAIL_SSL_TLS=False,
    USE_CREDENTIALS=True,
    VALIDATE_CERTS=True
)

async def send_email(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, email: str, username: str, body: str):
    message = MessageSchema(
        subject=f'Hi, {username}',
        recipients=[email],
        body=body,
        subtype='html'
    )
    
    fm = FastMail(conf)
    try:
        background_tasks.add_task(fm.send_message, message)
    except aiosmtplib.SMTPException as e:
        logging.error(f'An error occurred: {e}')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'An error occurred: {e}')

@user.post('/signup', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def user_sign_in(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, form: UserSignin, db: db_dependency):
    existing_username = db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.username == form.username).first()
    existing_email = db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.email == form.email).first()
    
    if existing_email:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail='Email already in use!')
    if existing_username:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail='Username already in use!')
    
    user = UserModel(
        firstname=form.firstname,
        lastname=form.lastname,
        username=form.username,
        email=form.email,
        password=hashed.hash(form.password),
        is_admin=True
    )
    
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(user)
    
    body = 'Congratulations on making the right choice to trade with us'
    await send_email(background_tasks, user.email, user.username, body)
    
    return 'Sign-up Successful'

I keep on getting an error saying invalid credentials or service not available
I've double-checked my credentials and email service configuration, but I can't seem to resolve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error message suggests there are network connection issues to Yahoo! SMTP Server. Please check if you can ping the server. If you are hosting on public cloud providers, they mostly block outgoing requests on port 587 to reduce misuse of their services being used for email spam.
